# CATransition not animating from method inside UIView subclass

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, caanimation, catransition

I have a method inside my UIView subclass which adds a to CATransition its `layer`:

```
- (void)animateWithDefaultTransition:(NSString *)transition duration:(CFTimeInterval)duration
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:transition];
    [animation setDuration:duration];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [animation setSubtype:@"fromRight"];

    [zoomView setHidden:NO];
    [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
}
```

I call it from another class like this:

```
[transitionView animateWithDefaultTransition:@"push" duration:1.0];
```

However `zoomView` simply appears and the transition isn't performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UIView` transition method:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
       duration:0.2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{
         [fromView removeFromSuperview];
         [containerView addSubview:toView];
       }
       completion:NULL];
```